Why don't these conditional foreach statements work?
I have a lot of loops embedded within each other, and I would like to use conditional logic on some of the loops, but I am encountering an error and am wondering why this is not possible.
To put it another way, I have a very long set of code (about 180 lines in my actual example). I want to run this code twice, but make a few alterations across the first and second (and potentially more) main loops. In general, when I need to do this, I just use if statement within the code, that are activated only for certain loops. However, in my current case, my alterations include needing to run different foreach statements in each of the two main loops. But using conditional logic on these loops doesn't work for some reason.
Here is a MWE of the essence of what I would like to do (my actual example is about 180 lines):
sysuse auto2, clear

foreach i in abc def {
    if "`i'"=="abc" foreach j in turn length trunk {
    if "`i'"=="def" foreach j in displacement {     
        if "`i'"=="def" keep if _n<10
        sum `j'
        local a_`i'_`j' = r(mean)
    }
    
    if "`i'"=="abc" foreach j in turn length trunk {
    if "`i'"=="def" foreach j in headroom trunk {
        if "`i'"=="def" keep if _n<10       
        sum `j'
        local b_`i'_`j' = r(min)
    }   
}

Basically, I have a bunch of code that I would like to loop through twice, but there are several differences between the loops. In the first loop, I would like to use a different set of variables in the loops than in the second instance. And I do not want to make a sample restriction in the first loop, while I would like to in the second. (In my actual application, I also have a different regression between loops 1 and 2).
I thought that I could use logic (if "``i'"=="...") to choose which of the inner loops I would like to use, but I am getting a r(612) (unexpected end of file) error. My best guess is that the { from if "``i'"=="def" foreach j in displacement { is for some reason not being ignored.
Note that this version works (where I comment out the second if statements), but obviously doesn't do what I need:
sysuse auto2, clear

foreach i in abc def {
    if "`i'"=="abc" foreach j in turn length trunk {
    *if "`i'"=="def" foreach j in displacement {        
        if "`i'"=="def" keep if _n<10
        sum `j'
        local a_`i'_`j' = r(mean)
    }
    
    if "`i'"=="abc" foreach j in turn length trunk {
    *if "`i'"=="def" foreach j in headroom trunk {
        if "`i'"=="def" keep if _n<10       
        sum `j'
        local b_`i'_`j' = r(min)
    }
}

Is there a way to use if with foreach (or otherwise salvage my code without having to just write the loops out separately)?
Note that this question relates to Forvalues within if statement.

Not the answer you seek, but candidly I wouldn't even try to do this. The problem is not that there isn't a way to do what you want -- I haven't tried -- it's just that your code is too hard for anyone to follow easily. Anyone here includes you in the future.
Let us take it that upstream code is supplying either abc or def as argument. I would structure the code starting as follows.
sysuse auto2, clear

if "`i'" == "abc" { 
    ...
}
else if "`i'" == "def" { 
    ...
}

Your MWE still looks pretty bizarre, but FWIW

keep in 1/9 is more direct than keep if _n < 10

If you only want a mean or a minimum out of summarize, use the meanonly option.



This makes sense. Thank you for the extra tips as well. (And I agree that my MWE is bizarre.)

In case anyone sees this, I have figured out a solution, though I am still not sure why it doesn't work in the original problem.
You just use define a varlist based on the value of the main loop. Then you can access this variable in the inner loop and avoid having to use two for statements:
sysuse auto2, clear

foreach i in abc def {
    if "`i'"=="abc" local vars turn length trunk
    if "`i'"=="def" local vars displacement 
        foreach j in `vars' {       
            if "`i'"=="def" keep if _n<10
            sum `j'
            local a_`i'_`j' = r(mean)
        }
}

